# Laravel Eloquent WhereHas Query After Union

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel and postgres to query a table called `LabTestVisit` . A user can have a payment_mode_id or a scheme_id. I have retrieved all the data by doing a union on both of the tables . When i query the results after doing union, i get the result of only one table, but i want combined results. Any ideas on how i can improve this?

My code

```
  $builder1 = LabTestVisit::select(
            DB::raw("count(*) as payment_count"),
            DB::raw("payment_modes.name as payment_name")
        )
            ->join('payment_mode_visits', 'payment_mode_visits.visit_id', 'lab_test_visits.visit_id')
            ->join('payment_modes', 'payment_modes.id', 'payment_mode_visits.payment_mode_id')
            ->whereBetween('lab_test_visits.created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->groupBy('payment_modes.name')
            ->whereNotNull('payment_modes.name');

        $builder2 = LabTestVisit::select(
            DB::raw("count(*) as payment_count"),
            DB::raw("schemes.name as payment_name")
        )
            ->join('payment_mode_visits', 'payment_mode_visits.visit_id', 'lab_test_visits.visit_id')
            ->leftJoin('schemes', 'schemes.id', 'payment_mode_visits.scheme_id')
            ->whereBetween('lab_test_visits.created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->whereNotNull('schemes.name')
            ->groupBy('schemes.name')
            ->union($builder1);

            
        $clinics = request('clinics', []);


        if (!empty($clinics) && is_array($clinics)) {
            $builder2->whereHas('visit.clinic', function ($query) use ($clinics) {
                $query->select([
                    DB::raw("DISTINCT *"),
                    DB::raw("count(*) OVER() AS filtered")
                ]);
                $query->whereIn('uuid', $clinics);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not merge both queries so you don't need a union? This will make the query faster and more readable.

```
$builder = LabTestVisit::select(
        DB::raw("count(*) as payment_count"),
        DB::raw("COALESCE(payment_modes.name, schemes.name) as payment_name")
    )
    ->join('payment_mode_visits', 'payment_mode_visits.visit_id', 'lab_test_visits.visit_id')
    ->leftJoin('payment_modes', 'payment_modes.id', 'payment_mode_visits.payment_mode_id')
    ->leftJoin('schemes', 'schemes.id', 'payment_mode_visits.scheme_id')
    ->whereBetween('lab_test_visits.created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->where(static function ($query) {
        $query
            ->whereNotNull('payment_modes.name')
            ->orWhereNotNull('schemes.name')
    })
    ->groupByRaw('COALESCE(payment_modes.name, schemes.name)');
```

This is a query I made from the information you provided. I wrote it by hand so it might contain some syntax mistakes, but it should do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I will need to add a join for the schemes table as well, which results in Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "name, schemes" .

Comment: Works perfectly, i changed the last line to         ```->groupBy(DB::raw('COALESCE(payment_modes.name, schemes.name)'));``` because im not using the latest version of laravel